# Continuous group action and convergent sequences.

Tags: general-topology, group-actions

I would like to see if the following statement is true in general.

Statement:
Let $G$ be a topological group acting on a topological space $X$ continuously.
Suppose that a sequence $g_n \in G$ and an element $x \in X$ satisfy $g_n \cdot x \to g \cdot x$ for some $g \in G$.
Then we have $g_n^{-1} \cdot x \to g^{-1} \cdot x$.

Unfortunately, I do not know whether the statement is true or not.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true, and in fact, you don't really even need to be taking a limit.  Let $G=O_2$, the group of $2\times 2$ orthogonal matrices, acting on $\mathbb R^2$, and let
$$g_n= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}\text{, } 
g = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\text{, }
x=\begin{bmatrix} 1  \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\text{,}$$
then $$g_n\cdot x= g\cdot x = \begin{bmatrix} 1  \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}\text{,}$$
yet $$g_n^{-1}\cdot x = \begin{bmatrix} 1  \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}\text{,}$$ whereas
$$ g^{-1}\cdot x=\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\text{.}$$

If $G$ is compact Abelian and both $G$ and $X$ are metrizable, then it is true, as you can verify by passing to subsequences for which $\{g^{-1}\cdot g_n\}$ converges to a member of the stabilizer of $x$, whereby so does $\{g\cdot g_n^{-1}\}$.

You could probably relax those assumptions too, though I don't know how much.

Comment: I was considering non-compact Lie group G = SL(n,R) acting on itself by conjugation, and initially I guessed that the above generalized version is also true.. which is no longer true by your counterexample. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @S.Y.Park No problem, glad I could help! (If you like the answer, feel free to upvote and accept as the answer.)

Comment: This question goes against [our quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.